# Connecting an Arduino to both panel and load side of charge controller, can this work?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, voltage-measurement, solar-charge-controller

I just joined this site because my searches haven't turned up an answer to this question, so apologies in advance if I missed something.

I have an Arduino powered by the load side of a 12V solar charge controller. I want it to measure the voltage of the panel side, but if my understanding of how charge controllers work is correct, connecting the load ground to panel ground would bypass the controller's MOSFETs, preventing it from doing its job. Is this correct?

For context, I'm trying to get the Arduino to detect when surplus power is available and send it to a fan or heater. I figured the solar panel voltage would be the best indicator of this, but if it would be worth making another question to discuss different methods I'll do that.

Comment: <<< connecting the load ground to panel ground would bypass the controller's MOSFETs, >>> A schematic would be useful ...

Comment: The solar panel voltage you measure in this set-up is determined by the MPPT (if any) of the solar controller or by the battery voltage. Said voltage is not a good measure, or at least not an easy measure, of how much surplus current there could be.

Comment: It depends on the charge controller. Some have a common ground for source and load and some do not. If it is the common ground type, then no problem. If it is NOT the common ground type, then you definitely cannot connect the grounds together on your Arduino board. Usually the common ground types have a warning in the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm almost sure the charge controller is the type that switches the ground lines and keeps the live lines connected, plus I want this to be compatible with any controller, so clearly a voltage divider or similar isn't going to do it. Just to clarify, I don't need it to know how much current is going to waste, only that the battery is full and the panel is in sunlight.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an isolated amplifier circuit to buffer the voltage from the panel to the Arduino or ADC, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard of isolated amplifiers. That seems like it should work.